# Java: How to get the number of items in a ShortBuffer?

Tags: java, android, buffer

I wonder how to get the number of items in a ShortBuffer.

I want the number of items that are really in the buffer, not the maximum capacity.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "the number of items that are really in the buffer"? Can you illustrate, with code, how this is different from capacity?

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html), "A buffer's capacity is the number of elements it contains.".

Comment: Dont get me wrong, but this question looks like it was written by a newbie who has 1 rep and spent 10 minutes here. I am sure, you can do better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Buffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/Buffer.html) is not a Collection, but a (comparatively thin) wrapper around a primitive array that provides some useful methods for operating on groups of primitive values. Like a primitive array, it always contains values for each valid index.

Therefore the number of items is always equal to its capacity.

It does not keep track of which indices have already been written to since its creation. And as one major use case is to [wrap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ShortBuffer.html#wrap(short%5B%5D)) an existing array while still reflecting all changes to the wrapped array, that would not even be possible to implement.

Answer (score 0):

`ShortBuffer` holds a `position` that keeps track on where to `put` elements. You can use it to know how many elements you put in. The number of elements always equals its capacity as others mentioned.

```
@Test
fun testShortBuffer() {

    val shortBuffer = ShortBuffer.allocate(1024)

    println(shortBuffer.position()) // position 0

    shortBuffer.put(1)
    println(shortBuffer.position()) // position 1

    shortBuffer.put(shortArrayOf(2, 3, 4))
    println(shortBuffer.position()) // position 4

    shortBuffer.clear()
    println(shortBuffer.position()) // position 0
}
```